# Parsing a templated string

Tags: javascript, json, regex, string, parsing

I have a string like this

```
const str = 'map("a")to("b");map("foo")to("bar");map("alpha")to("beta");'
```

I wanted to parse this string to generate a json something like

```
[{id: 'a', map: 'b'},
{id: 'foo', map: 'bar'},
{id: 'alpha', map: 'beta'}]
```

I was wondering if regex is the best way to do this or if theres any utility lib I could leverage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a regex that should work for your current case:

```js
const str = 'map("a")to("b");map("foo")to("bar");map("alpha")to("beta");';

const res = str.split(";").map(e => {
  const k = e.match(/map\("(.+?)"\)to\("(.+?)"\)/);
  return k && k.length === 3 ? {id: k[1], map: k[2]} : null;
}).filter(e => e);

console.log(res);
```

The idea is to split on semicolons (a lookaround could be used to handle cases when semicolons are part of your desired key/value), then `map` these pairs into the desired object format based on a regex that parses the `map("")to("")` format. Finally, `null`s are filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there is a nice regex solution which is shorter and faster, but since i'm bad at regex i solve those things like that:

```
const str = 'map("a")to("b");map("foo")to("bar");map("alpha")to("beta");'

const result = str.split(';').map(e => {

  const parts = e.substring(3).split('to').map(item => item.replace(/\W/g, ''));

  return {
    id: parts[0],
    map: parts[1]
  };
})
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Just have to slice off the last element in the split...otherwise result[3] is `{id: "", map: undefined}`